# In an IntelliJ Kotlin project, when I try to run a java class, I get a "Could not find or load main class" error

Tags: java, kotlin, intellij-idea

I try to run the class from the green arrow in IntelliJ and I get the "Could not find or load main class"  error. If I try to run the class from the terminal by running

```
javac <filename.java>
java <filename>
```

it works. I tried to do "rebuild project" and to make a new project and it did not change anything.

Here is a photo of my project:

[image]

Here is a photo of my Run-Edit configurations

[image]

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Your java code needs to be placed in `src/main/java` directory instead of `src/main/kotlin`.

Kotlin compiler doesn't compile Java files in Kotlin source roots, Java compiler doesn't compile Java files in Kotlin source roots, therefore `.class` files are not created by any of the compilers and you get this error.

The solution is to move `*.java` files into `src/main/java` directory. Create this directory manually if it doesn't exist.

Comment: I'm having a bit of trouble creating that java directory. From what I understand it should be a module, but when I try to do right-click on main and click "new | module", select java and click next, I get a java.iml file, instead of getting a blue module directory like the kotlin directory. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: No, you just create it in the same module under `main` directory. Right click on `main`, new | directory | type "java".

Comment: Thanks man, I was going crazy looking for the solution.